# electron webview not firing 'dom-ready' event after been packed

Tags: javascript, node.js, webview, electron, electron-builder

I'm using a webview inside electron app, here is my code:

```
<webview id="weather" src="http://example.com"></webview>

const weather = document.getElementById("weather")
    weather.addEventListener('console-message', (e) => {
        console.log('weather page log: ', e.message)
    })
    weather.addEventListener('dom-ready', (e) => {
        var currentURL = e.target.getURL();
        if (currentURL === "http://example.com") {
            e.target.executeJavaScript("some script");
        }
    })
```

The code worked when use electron start.But the weird thing is that after I packed my application with electron-builder,the dom-ready event wasn't even fired(tested with alert,no alert).

index.js

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1360,
        height: 720,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'icon.ico'),
        thickFrame: true,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            webSecurity: false,
            contextIsolation: false,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            webviewTag: true,
            experimentalFeatures: true,
            partition:"browser_window"
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
```

DevelopEnvironment(package.json):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^27.0.2",
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.4",
    "electron-icon-builder": "^2.0.1"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "electron-store": "^8.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2"
  }
```

nodejs version v16.17.0
npm version 8.19.1

Comment: Hi, I also use webviews with a "dom-ready" event listener in one of my Electron applications and I don't have the problem when I package the application. Maybe try embedding your if condition in the "did-stop-loading" event and test with an alert. Or maybe it comes from to document.getElementById which refers to your webview. In my case, I use React and the useRef hook to refer to my webview. All the best